# Export graphics from R in vector format

Tags: r, vector-graphics

I'd like to export graphics from R (for example, histograms and ROC curves) in vector format in order to make layout edits in a graphic design program like Intaglio. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving plots to pdf fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494370/saving-plots-to-pdf-fails).  Not a great duplicate, but this question is definitely in the manuals *everywhere*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pdf("myfile.pdf")

# graph goes here

dev.off()
```

Other devices (besides PDF) exist as well.  (@Justin points out what is probably the most useful one in a comment).

Comment: If the OP is looking for vector graphics, `?svg` from `grDevices`