# R output to screen error

Tags: r, output

I get Rscript error of:

> Error in dev.copy2pdf(file = fname, out.type = "pdf") :
>         can only print from a screen device
>       Execution halted

I am running the following R source in my Mac OSX console with:

```
Rscript --vanulla charts.R
```

I am using R version 3.3.2. Here is my source:

```
library(quantmod)

sym <- 'IBM'    
d <- getSymbols(sym,src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)

chartSeries(d, name = sym, theme = "white", bar.type = 'ohlc', 
            line.type = "l",TA = "addVo();addSMA()",
            subset = 'last 6 months') 

addRSI()

dev <- dev.prev() 
fname <- sprintf("%s.pdf",sym)
dev.copy2pdf(file = fname, out.type = "pdf")
dev.off()
```

How do I fix the `dev.copy2pdf()` if I want to output a PDF running on the conole. It runs fine within my RStudio,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed it

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625394/problem-saving-pdf-file-in-r-with-ggplot2
pdf(fname)
chartSeries(d, name=sym, theme="white",bar.type='ohlc',line.type="l",TA="addRSI();addVo();addBBands();addSMA()",subset='last 6 months')
dev.off()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain exactly how: Do not use `dev.copy2pdf()` or `dev.print()` after compiling the figure, but instead `pdf()` before.